# How to enable auto-completion for \gls* and friends in TeXstudio when using package glossaries-extra with bib2gls?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

It is standard behaviour of TeXstudio to autocomplete certain commands with arguments. For example, when correctly set up, `\cite` commands will offer bibliography entries, `\ref` will provide created labels and so forth.

With `bib2gls` and `glossaries-extra`, one also uses an external `.bib`-file to define entries for a glossary. However, contrary to the above,

- no autofill or autocomplete is provided when using `\gls*`;
- incorrect options are displayed for `\gls`, namely labels created for theorems, definitions and so on.

The editor displays an empty white pop-up window when adding an argument to `\gls*`:
[image: No autocomplete for \gls*]

Checking `glossaries-extra-bib2gls-cwl` under `Options`->`Configure TeXstudio`->`Completion`->`Permanently active completion files` with `Show Advanced Options` enabled does not work.

***Q:*** Is it possible to enable the autocomplete feature for `\gls*` and friends for `bib2gls` and `glossaries-extra` as well?

---

MWE (compiled with option `bib2gls -g`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record, stylemods={default}, style={alttreehypergroup}]{glossaries-extra}
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={entriesTest}, break-at={none}]

\begin{document}
    Sample text.
    \gls*{test-entry} % retype "test-entry" to reproduce
    \renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]}
    {\printunsrtglossary[type=main]}
\end{document}
```

`entriesTest.bib`:

```
@entry{test-entry,
name={fake name},
text={},
description={fictional description}
}
```

Log file (with user name changed):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.29)  15 SEP 2023 23:52
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./AutocompleteTest.tex
(AutocompleteTest.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hypertext links for LaTeX

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-08-07 v2.53 Cross-referencing by name of section

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count194
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count195
)
\@linkdim=\dimen141
\Hy@linkcounter=\count196
\Hy@pagecounter=\count197

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count198

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `hypertexnames' set `false' on input line 4050.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4167.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4172.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4175.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4434.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count199

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4772.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen142

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count266
\Field@Width=\dimen143
\Fld@charsize=\dimen144
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6051.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6056.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6059.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6066.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6081.

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count267
\c@Item=\count268
\c@Hfootnote=\count269
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2023-07-08 v7.01b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count270
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count271

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip50
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries-extra\glossaries-extra.sty
Package: glossaries-extra 2023/06/28 v1.52 (NLCT)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count272
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/base\glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2022/10/14 v2.08 (NLCT)
\@glsmfirst=\toks20
\@glsmrest=\toks21
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/xfor\xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/datatool\datatool-base.sty
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks22
\ex@=\dimen145
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen146
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count273
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count274
\leftroot@=\count275
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count276
\DOTSCASE@=\count277
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen147
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count278
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count279
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count280
\dspbrk@lvl=\count281
\tag@help=\toks23
\row@=\count282
\column@=\count283
\maxfields@=\count284
\andhelp@=\toks24
\eqnshift@=\dimen148
\alignsep@=\dimen149
\tagshift@=\dimen150
\tagwidth@=\dimen151
\totwidth@=\dimen152
\lineht@=\dimen153
\@envbody=\toks25
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks26
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/substr\substr.sty
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count285
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/datatool\datatool-fp.sty
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp.sty
Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\defpattern.sty
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count286
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count287
\FP@xia=\count288
\FP@xib=\count289
\FP@xfa=\count290
\FP@xfb=\count291
\FP@rega=\count292
\FP@regb=\count293
\FP@regs=\count294
\FP@times=\count295
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-addons.sty
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-exp.sty
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-trigo.sty
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-pas.sty
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-random.sty
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count296
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-eqn.sty
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-upn.sty
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/fp\fp-eval.sty
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks27
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count297
\dtl@tmplength=\skip54
\dtl@sortresult=\count298
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count299
\@dtl@datatype=\count300
\dtl@codeA=\count301
\dtl@codeB=\count302
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count303
)
\gls@level=\count304
\@gls@tmpb=\toks28
\gls@tmplen=\skip55
\glskeylisttok=\toks29
\glslabeltok=\toks30
\glsshorttok=\toks31
\glslongtok=\toks32

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-hypernav.sty
Package: glossary-hypernav 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip56
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/tools\longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2021-09-01 v4.17 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip57
\LTright=\skip58
\LTpre=\skip59
\LTpost=\skip60
\LTchunksize=\count305
\LTcapwidth=\dimen154
\LT@head=\box53
\LT@firsthead=\box54
\LT@foot=\box55
\LT@lastfoot=\box56
\LT@gbox=\box57
\LT@cols=\count306
\LT@rows=\count307
\c@LT@tables=\count308
\c@LT@chunks=\count309
\LT@p@ftn=\toks33
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip61
\glspagelistwidth=\skip62
)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/supertabular\supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count310
\ST@wd=\dimen155
\ST@rightskip=\skip63
\ST@leftskip=\skip64
\ST@parfillskip=\skip65
\ST@pageleft=\dimen156
\ST@headht=\dimen157
\ST@tailht=\dimen158
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen159
\ST@pboxht=\dimen160
\ST@lineht=\dimen161
\ST@prevht=\dimen162
\ST@toadd=\dimen163
\ST@dimen=\dimen164
\ST@pbox=\box58
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2022/11/03 v4.52 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip66
))
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries-extra\glossaries-extra-bib2gls.sty
Package: glossaries-extra-bib2gls 2023/06/28 v1.52 (NLCT)
)
\@glsxtr@leveloffset=\count311
\glsxtrresourcecount=\count312
\@glsxtrnewgls@inner=\count313
\glsshortpltok=\toks34
\glslongpltok=\toks35

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries-extra\glossaries-extra-abbrstyles.
def
File: glossaries-extra-abbrstyles.def 2023/06/28 v1.52 (NLCT)
)
\mglselementindex=\count314

(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/glossaries-extra\glossaries-extra-stylemods.s
ty
Package: glossaries-extra-stylemods 2023/06/28 v1.52 (NLCT)
\glsxtrAltTreeIndent=\skip67
\glsxtrtreetopindent=\skip68
)) (AutocompleteTest.glstex)
(C:\Users\UserNameChanged\MikTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count315
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box59
)
(AutocompleteTest.aux)
\openout1 = `AutocompleteTest.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6.
 (AutocompleteTest.out) (AutocompleteTest.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `AutocompleteTest.out'.

 [1{C:/Users/UserNameChanged/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}

] [2

] [3

]
(AutocompleteTest.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
 ***********
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `AutocompleteTest.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 5A286D8900DEC91C1C9BB16C09D37EB3;84.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15331 strings out of 475465
 258023 string characters out of 5770800
 1918248 words of memory out of 5000000
 36446 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 559336 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 109i,5n,107p,6044b,556s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/UserNameChanged/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Users/R
asmus/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Users/UserNameChanged/MikTeX/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on AutocompleteTest.pdf (3 pages, 40218 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 46 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 9 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Build information:

```
TeXstudio 4.5.2 (git 4.5.2)
Using Qt Version 6.5.0, compiled with Qt 6.5.0 R
Microsoft Windows 11 Pro 10.0.22621
MiKTeX full distribution (August 2023)
```

Comment: This is not currently possible. You can make a feature request at the [github page](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio)

Comment: @mbert Thank you. A feature request has been opened: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/3299.